# When group G has a nonidentity finite normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $ \vartriangle ^{+} (G)$ be the set of all elements of finite order which have finitely many conjugates in G. Prove if $ \vartriangle ^+ (G)\neq 1$
then G has a nonidentity finite normal subgroup.

My effort:
There exists a nonidentity element $a \in {\vartriangle} ^{+} (G)$, now let H denotes the subgroup generated by a and all its conjugates, now H is normal, and nonidentity, but it is just finitely generated I cannot show why it is finite.